# Why do I have so many DeadlineExceededErrors with google-app-engine-django?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm using google-app-engine-django to run Django 1.1 on Google App Engine and I'm getting lots and lots of DeadlineExceededErrors, sometimes with . My entire app is quite simple, and it's happening throughout my app, so I suspect that there is a problem with my basic settings. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Sample error:

```
<class 'google.appengine.runtime.DeadlineExceededError'>: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/coffeeshopprapp/1.337356339816540588/main.py", line 38, in <module>
    import django.core.handlers.wsgi
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.1/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.core.urlresolvers import set_script_prefix
  File "/base/python_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.1/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 8, in <module>
    """
```

app.yaml

```
application: coffeeshopprapp
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /media
  static_dir: media

- url: /admin.*
  script: main.py
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

main.py

```
import os
import sys
import logging

from appengine_django import InstallAppengineHelperForDjango
InstallAppengineHelperForDjango()

from appengine_django import have_django_zip
from appengine_django import django_zip_path

# Google App Engine imports.
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util

# Import the part of Django that we use here.
import django.core.handlers.wsgi

def main():
  # Ensure the Django zipfile is in the path if required.
  if have_django_zip and django_zip_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.insert(1, django_zip_path)

  # Create a Django application for WSGI.
  application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

  # Run the WSGI CGI handler with that application.
  util.run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

settings.py

```
import os

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = (
    # ('Your Name', 'your_email@domain.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASE_ENGINE = 'appengine' 
DATABASE_NAME = ''
DATABASE_USER = ''
DATABASE_PASSWORD = ''
DATABASE_HOST = ''
DATABASE_PORT = ''

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

USE_I18N = True

MEDIA_ROOT = ''

MEDIA_URL = ''

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = '/media/'

SECRET_KEY = 'some_secret_key'

EMAIL_HOST = ''

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.load_template_source',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware'
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'

ROOT_PATH = os.path.dirname(__file__)
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(ROOT_PATH, 'templates')
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'appengine_django',
     'coffeeshoppr' # my app
)
```

Comment: None of the code in main gets executed, as the exception's in the last import -- so it's essentially impossible to help you with this info. How are the settings.py you're using for Django?  I imagine your bug must be hiding there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug that occurs intermittently for some apps. We're working on fixing it ASAP.

Comment: We being the team behind Google App Engine, google-app-engine-django, or Django? How can I help solve it?

Comment: Google App Engine. Unfortunately, there's not much you can do, except to try and minimise the amount of stuff you import, which helps with execution time in any case.

Comment: Ouch. Do you know of any ETA on a fix?

Comment: You can look @ http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1695 for more info.